# How to convert Stream<Character> to a Map<Character, Set<Character>>

Tags: java, java-stream

Can someone please help complete the following function using Java streams?

```
// Example 
// Input: [a, b, a, c]
// Output: { a => emptyHashSet, b => emptyHashSet, c => emptyHashSet }
// emptySet above means an empty HashSet<Character>
Map<Character, Set<Character>> transform(final Stream<Character> chars) {
// todo
}
```

I tried the following:

```
Map<Character, Set<Character>> transform(final Stream<Character> chars) {
    return chars.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), HashSet::new));
}
```

This resulted in:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate
> key a (attempted merging values [] and [])

I tried the suggestion in the comments:

```
Map<Character, Set<Character>> transform(final Stream<Character> chars) {
    return chars.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), HashSet::new, (a, b) -> {
            a.addAll(b);
            return a;
        }));
}
```

It worked, thanks!

Are there any more simpler ways to do it?

Comment: What do you mean, it didn't work because of duplicates?  You can always use a Collectors.toMap overload that specifies how to deal with duplicates.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. Thanks for the suggestion, it works! Is this the idiomatic way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:  Assume `List<Character> chars` is populated.

```
Map<Character, Set<Character>>   map = chars.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a,
                           Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)));
```

But since sets don't hold duplicates, the set will only hold one value.  And that value and the key will be the same. So I don't see any purpose in this since you will be using a key to retrieve a set containing the key.

Try it like this to see the difference.  `GroupingBy` defaults to a `list` for the map value.

```
 Map<Character, List<Character>> map = chars.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a));
```